# Python 3, PyQt5, Mac OSx, and Sublme Text: Import Error

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, sublimetext3

In the process of trying to get my environment working, I may have installed things both using Homebrew and without. Either way, my current situation is as follows:

Python 3 is installed via Homebrew and works with IDLE and Sublime Text.
PyQt5 imports work and are functional with IDLE.

In Sublime Text (and in PyCharm), it is still using Python 3 but PyQt5 imports give the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Documents/PythonWorkspace/testing.py", line 8, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow
ImportError: No module named PyQt5.QtWidgets
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/username/Documents/PythonWorkspace/testing.py"]
[dir: /Users/username/Documents/PythonWorkspace]
[path: “/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin”]
```

As far as I can tell, the issue has something to do with Paths. It looks like Sublime Text is utilizes paths based on the file called "paths" At some point, I seem to have added to this file to allow it to discover Python3 and SIP. Whereas the IDLE installation seems to be linked to bash_profile and sys.path

I feel like I'm getting closer to a working environment but any help would be appreciated, particularly when it comes to understanding why this issue is occurring. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text runs the following shell command:

```
python -u "/Users/username/Documents/PythonWorkspace/testing.py"
```

So we need to know where actually this "python" resides. Try running this in console:

```
which python
```

If you get something like ***/usr/bin/python***, so we can say, that Sublime Text tries to feed your script to system osx python, which is 2.7 actually. Try running "which python3" to check if the symlink to python3 executable is created. If its not, you can do it yourself and than just use it.

I would recommend you to add a new python3 build system to Sublime Text (to not mess with the system python). Create a file:

```
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Python 3.sublime-build
```

with the content, something like (you can use your symlink to python3 instead of a path):

```
{
    "cmd": ["/path/to/your/python3", "$file"]
}
```

and try running your script with "Tools -> Build system -> Python 3"  enabled in Sublime Text.

The more advanced build system layout may look like:

```
    {
    "path": "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin",
    "env":
        {
            "PYTHONPATH":"/usr/local/lib/python:/usr/local/username/python/3.3/lib/python3.3/"
        },
    "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "encoding": "utf-8",
    "env": {"LANG": "ru_RU.UTF-8"}
    }
```